# Multiple Custom Spinner always sets values to one spninner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have two Spinner in my layout. First one to select vehicle, second one for choose color from the shorted list of that particular vehicle. eg.(selected Bajaj, second need to show list of color of that vehicle already saved)

Here I did getting all datas from database for vehicle and for color. Both values are in my hand. But if I select vehicle type in Spinner1, it was showing the color of that vehicles in same spinner instead of, showing in Spinner2. First I had same (Spinner getset class, adapter class,custom layout). Now I created all three as different. Even now also getting the same problem.

How to find, where I am doing wrong. Below is the code I am using.

```
  public void setListData()// gets vehicles value from DB
{   
    List<VehicleGetSetter> contacts = vdb.getVehicleListToCustomer(vendor_id);
    for (VehicleGetSetter cn : contacts) {
        final BikeSpinner sched = new BikeSpinner();
                    sched.setBikeName("Select Bike");
            CustomListBikeName.add(sched); 
        }}

   private void setBikeAdapterValues() {// set Vehicle value in Spinner1
    Resources res = getResources();
    adapter = new BikeSpinnerAdapter(NewCustomer.this, R.layout.bike_spinner, CustomListBikeName,res);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
            bike_no_from_adapter   = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textbike_numbr)).getText().toString();
            what_bike   = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textbike)).getText().toString();
            String OutputMsg = "Selected : \n\n"+bike_no_from_adapter;
            if(position!=0){
                setListBikeColor(bike_no_from_adapter);
            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Must Select Vehicle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

  public void setListBikeColor(String bike_no_from_adapter){// get color of selected vehicles from DB
    List<VehicleGetSetter> contacts1 = vdb.getVehicleColorListToCustomer(vendor_id,bike_no_from_adapter);
    for (VehicleGetSetter cn1 : contacts1) {
        final BikeSpinn sched1 = new BikeSpinn();
                    sched1.setBikeNumber(cn1.getColor());
            CustomListBikeColor.add(sched1);
            setBikeAdapterValuesColor();
        }
}


  private void setBikeAdapterValuesColor() {// trying to set value in second spinner, but setting in same vehicle spinner.
    Resources res2 = getResources();
    coloradapter = new BikeSpinnerColor(NewCustomer.this, R.layout.bike_spinner_color, CustomListBikeColor,res2);
    cust_bike_color.setAdapter(coloradapter);
    cust_bike_color.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Get selected row data to show on screen
            bike_no_from_adapter   = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textbike_numbr)).getText().toString();
            what_bike   = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textbike)).getText().toString();

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Must Select Vehicle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

MainLayout which contain Spinner

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_blue"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bike"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Bike Details" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cust_bike"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cust_bike_color"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cust_bike_number"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Custom layout for spinners(Similar for both spinner(named differently))

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textbike"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textbike_numbr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom ArrayAdapterClass(Having Two similar class for two Spinners)

```
 public class BikeSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

 private Activity activity;
 private ArrayList data;
  public Resources res;
  BikeSpinner tempValues=null;
  LayoutInflater inflater;
  public BikeSpinnerAdapter(NewCustomer activitySpinner, 
                     int textViewResourceId,   
                     ArrayList objects,
                     Resources resLocal
                    ) 
 {
   super(activitySpinner, textViewResourceId, objects);

   activity = activitySpinner;
   data     = objects;
   res      = resLocal;

   inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 }

 @Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)        {
   return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
 }

 public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bike_spinner, parent, false);

   tempValues = null;
   tempValues = (BikeSpinner) data.get(position);

   TextView label        = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textbike_numbr);
   TextView sub          = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textbike);

       label.setText(tempValues.getBikeName());
       sub.setText(tempValues.getBikeNumber());
   return row;
 }
 }
```

Comment: final BikeSpinner sched = new BikeSpinner().Where is your layout.xml?

Comment: How are you getting values in list ??

Comment: Thanks tiny sunlight,  vivek mishra.   I added the layout.  Values are getting properly. If I select the vehicle from Spinner 1, the color the getting correctly. But, the color(Red) is replacing the value of Spinner1, instead of loading into the Spinner2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this I achieved with multiple Spinner related with one another

Seperate class to set Dropdown List Adapters

```
  public void setListBikeName(String vr_id)
{   vendor_id=vr_id;
    List<VehicleGetSetter> contacts = ((NewCustomer)context).vdb.getVehicleListToCustomer(vendor_id);
    for (VehicleGetSetter cn : contacts) {
        final BikeSpinner sched = new BikeSpinner();
                if(cn.getModelYear().equals(""))
                    sched.setBikeName("Select Bike");
                else
                    sched.setBikeName(cn.getModelYear());
            ((NewCustomer)context).CustomListBikeName.add(sched); /** Take Model Object in ArrayList */
        }         
}

public void setListBikeColor(String name){
    ((NewCustomer)context).CustomListBikeColor.clear();
    List<VehicleGetSetter> contacts = ((NewCustomer)context).vdb.getVehicleColorListToCustomer(vendor_id,name);
    for (VehicleGetSetter cn : contacts) {
        final BikeSpinner sched = new BikeSpinner();

                    sched.setBikeName(cn.getColor());

                ((NewCustomer)context).CustomListBikeColor.add(sched); /** Take Model Object in ArrayList */
                ((NewCustomer)context).colorAdapterIntermediater();

        }
}

public void setListBikeNumber(String name,String color){
    ((NewCustomer)context).CustomListBikeNumber.clear();
    List<VehicleGetSetter> contacts = ((NewCustomer)context).vdb.getVehicleNumberListToCustomer(vendor_id,name,color);
    for (VehicleGetSetter cn : contacts) {
        final BikeSpinner sched = new BikeSpinner();

                    sched.setBikeName(cn.getNumber());

                ((NewCustomer)context).CustomListBikeNumber.add(sched); /** Take Model Object in ArrayList */
                ((NewCustomer)context).numberAdapterIntermediater();

        }
}

public void setBikeAdapterValues(ArrayList<BikeSpinner> CustomListBikeName,BikeSpinnerAdapter adapter,
        Spinner mySpinner,final String str,Resources res) {
    res = context.getResources();
    Spinner temp=mySpinner;
    adapter = new BikeSpinnerAdapter((NewCustomer) context, R.layout.bike_spinner, CustomListBikeName,res);
    temp.setAdapter(adapter);
    temp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
            if(str.equals("name")){
                bike_name_from_adapter   = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textbike_numbr)).getText().toString();
                    setListBikeColor(bike_name_from_adapter);
                }
            else if(str.equals("color")){
                bike_color_from_adapter   = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textbike_numbr)).getText().toString();
                setListBikeNumber(bike_name_from_adapter, bike_color_from_adapter);
            }
            else if(str.equals("number")){
                bike_no_from_adapter   = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textbike_numbr)).getText().toString();

                if(bike_no_from_adapter.length()>=10){
                    ((NewCustomer)context).last_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                     
                }
                else
                    ((NewCustomer)context).last_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((NewCustomer)context).passBikeValueToCustomer(bike_name_from_adapter,bike_color_from_adapter,bike_no_from_adapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

In the Main Class:

```
    bikeadapterobj.setListBikeName(_id);        
    bikeadapterobj.setBikeAdapterValues(CustomListBikeName,adapter,mySpinner,"name",res);
   public void colorAdapterIntermediater(){
    bikeadapterobj.setBikeAdapterValues(CustomListBikeColor,coloradapter,cust_bike_color,"color",res);
}

public void numberAdapterIntermediater(){
    bikeadapterobj.setBikeAdapterValues(CustomListBikeNumber,numberadapter,cust_bike_number,"number",res);
}
public void passBikeValueToCustomer(String name,String colr,String bkno){

        bike_name=name;
        bike_color=colr;
        bike_reg_number=bkno;
        Log.d("Bike Details : ", bike_name+" "+bike_color+" "+bike_reg_number);
    }
```